# Sending login data to website from iOS where website form has "onSubmit" method encrypts that the password

Tags: javascript, ios, post, encryption, forms

I am trying to create an iOS application that allows the user to log in to a certain website (which I have no affiliation with). I have tried to create a POST request with the username and password that the user enters into my app, but this does not work because, after playing around with Firefox's developer tools, I discovered that the website uses a form with an onSubmit method that calls some javascript to encrypt the password as it submits the form. When I create the POST request, this does not trigger the onSubmit method so the password is sent over unencrypted, and does not match. If I hardcode my encrypted password (which I found through Firefox's developer tools) into the POST request then it does work, but obviously only for my account.

So my questions are:

How can I fill out the form and trigger the onSubmit method from my iOS app, and then still be able to scrub data from the website after I log in?

I do have access to the javascript encryption file, so should I run the password through there before putting it into the POST request? And if so, then how?

Should I maybe be using a UIWebView/WKWebView instead of making a POST request? And if so, then how?

Comment: You need to convert that js encryption into your app (use obj/swift) then encrypt the password entered in your app before POST.

Comment: Arguably the easiest thing to do would be to replicate the "encryption" code in your own app.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried to do it but it proved too difficult because the encryption is very complex and in Javascript, so I could not translate it to obj-c. Are there any other solutions?